# Django models, how to convert existing UUID field to Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have and existing database where I have models.py as follows:

```
class basicData(models.Model):

    companyId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    companyName  = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    emailIdCompany = models.EmailField(max_length=1000,blank=False,null=True)
    numberOfEmployees = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    contactNumberCompany = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)

class extraData(models.Model):

   companyId = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   interaction = JSONField(db_index=True,null=True)
```

I want to update the models.py as follows:

```
class basicData(models.Model):

        companyId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        companyName  = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
        emailIdCompany = models.EmailField(max_length=1000,blank=False,null=True)
        numberOfEmployees = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
        contactNumberCompany = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)

class extraData(models.Model):

    companyId = models.ForeignKey(globalcompaniesbasicdatabase)
    interaction = JSONField(db_index=True,null=True)
```

How should I do this without loss of data.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Django support for doing this out-of-the-box, you'll have to write a custom migration (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/writing-migrations/). However, that should not be too hard.

The sneaky way around this is to realize that, internally, Django stores `ForeignKey` in the db as the ID of the foreign item, so the database would not be changed. If you make an automatic migration for this change, do not apply it and convince Django that you have applied it (extra row in migrations table will do), it might just work. Note altering migrations is not a good idea.

Comment: do you have any reference how should i write migration for this?

Comment: Create a new ForeignKey field, then write custom migration which iterates over all instances and copies id to the foreign key, then delete the original field and rename the foreign key. For the custom migration part, refer to the docs I attached in my previous comment, it's very well written.

Comment: Did same, anyways thanks !!